# Saving HTML data from URL

Tags: javascript, angular, filesaver.js

I need to show an external HTML5 content on my web page (using Angular 6).
I can't use iFrame tag because the server allows only "same origin".
I've tried to use FileSaver.js, but how can I save the HTML content and then show it on my website?

Comment: You want to load that data client-side?  You can only do that if the origin supports CORS.  Otherwise, you'll have to do this server-side.

Comment: Yes Client side, the origin does not support CORS. does is possible to download the html content to a file or other buffer and than show it?. this way I won't use the url directly.

Comment: No, if the origin doesn't support CORS you cannot load it client-side without proxying it server-side.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a file-url you can use `blob` and `URL.createObjectURL` to make it usable for `iFrame` (displaying)

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser'
constructor(sanitizer : DomSanitizer)

let blob = new Blob([urlString]);
this.frameSrc = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
```

If you need to download possibility, just create a `<a download ...></a>` tag with file-url as `href`

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about how it works on Angular but this might help.
I've done this in Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById("includeHeader").innerHTML = content.headerContent;
});
```

Where I have a js file containing html.

```
var content = {
headerContent: 
'YOUR HTML HERE' }
```

The idea is to inject code into your HTML using Javascript from a local source.